# ARIMA vs. ADL model

Tags: arima, model-comparison, ardl

I have estimated an MA(3) model and an ADL model on the differenced US unemployment rate. However, I'm in doubt as how to compare the two models?
Does it make sense to compare them using information critera such as AIC and BIC? Or should I rather use e.g. MSE or other error measures?

Thanks in advance!